# CentOS 7 install Octave 4.0.2 with GUI (OpenGL support)

Tags: centos, octave, centos7

I'm trying to install Octave 4 from source code in CentOS 7 but I got the warning messages:

```
configure: WARNING: OpenGL libs (GL and GLU) not found.  Native graphics will be disabled.
configure: WARNING: OpenGL libs (GL and GLU) not found -- disabling GUI
configure: WARNING: 
configure: WARNING: I didn't find the necessary libraries to compile native
configure: WARNING: graphics.  It isn't necessary to have native graphics,
configure: WARNING: but you will need to have gnuplot installed or you won't
configure: WARNING: be able to use any of Octave's plotting commands
configure: WARNING: 
configure: 
configure: NOTE: Libraries or auxiliary programs may be skipped if they are
configure: NOTE: not found OR if they are missing required features on your
configure: NOTE: system.
```

I have checked this [QUESTION](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244565/compiling-octave-4-with-opengl-x11-configure-script-linking-error) but it didn't help.

I have also done `yum install libqt4-opengl-dev` but got an error `No package libqt4-opengl-dev available.`

I have got mesa-libGL and mesa-libGL-devel, but it seems like the configure cannot pick up these libraries.

**Edit: answer to my own question**
please see comments below the question.

Comment: Have you read http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Red_Hat_Linux_systems#CentOS ?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I still got the above warnings.

Comment: Then upload the config.log to a pastebin service and add the link here

Comment: I haven't found a service that allow me to upload 45k lines of logs for free :(

Comment: I think this might have something to do with the version of my source code. After I cloned the latest source, then run ./configure does not give me opengl warnings anymore and build with GUI option is turned on. I still have some compilation error but at least some progress made.

Comment: You should habe mentioned that you're trying to compile code from the hg repo and not the official released source tarball. Which branch do you try to build?

Comment: I just did hg clone http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave, now after sorting out other dependencies, all goes smoothly. thanks, Andy. Your initial comment was actually quite helpful!

Comment: After clone you are in the default branch (aka development). Don't expect that this always works without problems. You also habe to run ./bootstrap in the source dir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110510/discussion-between-andy-and-james).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that it's an old question, but I wanted to leave it in case if someone is still looking for an easy way of installing Octave 4.x.
The easiest way to install Octave 4 is to use Flatpack. It's installed by default in CentOS 7.

```
flatpak install flathub org.octave.Octave
flatpak run org.octave.Octave
```

If you're using Red Hat you need to install flatpak it first:

```
sudo yum install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```